# Define multiple classes at runtime using Unsafe.defineClass

Tags: java, instrumentation, unsafe, verifyerror, jvm-bytecode

I am working on a REPL for a custom programming language of mine. It is implemented on top of the compiler, which it uses to generate the bytecode for the input and convert it to a `Class<?>` instance using the `sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(String, byte[], int, int, ClassLoader, ProtectionDomain)` method. The relevant code looks like this (irrelevant parts like exception handling omitted):

```
void compileAndLoad(List<ICompilable> compilables)
{
    List<Class<?>> classes = ...;
    for (ICompilable c : compilables)
    {
        classes.add(compile(compilable));
    }
    for (Class<?> c : classes)
    {
        UNSAFE.ensureClassInitialized(c);
    }
}

// CLASS_LOADER = Enclosing.class.getClassLoader()
// PROTECTION_DOMAIN = Enclosing.class.getClassLoader()

Class<?> compile(ICompilable compilable)
{
    byte[] bytecode = genBytecode(compilable);
    String name = compilable.getFullName() // e.g. 'foo.bar.Baz'
    return UNSAFE.defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length, CLASS_LOADER, PROTECTION_DOMAIN);
}
```

Say the input requires multiple classes to be compiled and loaded.

```
> class A { interface B { }; func b() = new B { /* anonymous class */ } }
```

The `compilables` list has the contents

```
[ repl.Result_0, repl.Result_0$A, repl.Result_0$A$0, repl.Result_0$A$B ]
```

The `repl.Result_0$A` class depends on the `repl.Result_0$A$0` (anonymous) class and the `repl.Result_0$B` class and references their names in the bytecode. When defining it using `Unsafe`, the following error will occur:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: repl/Result_0$A$B
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
    at MyClass.compile(MyClass.java:42)
    // ... snip
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: repl.Result_0$A$B
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

I know this could be solved by reordering the list and defining `repl.Result_0$A$B` first, but that would not be a general solution since there can be references from `B -> A` as well.

**Is there a way to define and load multiple classes using `Unsafe.defineClass` without causing verification errors for unresolved classes?**

Comment: Have you tried using the Java compiler API instead of Unsafe? You can create your own JavaFileObject implementation which provides the bytecode, then use your own ClassLoader to load the classes using the FileObjects... I don't know enough of your compiler to know if this would work, but I am using this approach to compile classes at runtime and I never ran into this problem.

Comment: I like a guy with this kind of interest ;) Anyway, Renato is right, use some library to properly form a class and then use normal class loader to load them.

Comment: Why are you using Unsafe instead of ClassLoader.defineClass?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom because the method is `protected`

Comment: Yes, you need to write a ClassLoader subclass, instantiate it, then call loadClass, which can load a byte[] from wherever and pass it to loadClass. The ClassLoader Javadoc gives an example of how a network class loader might be implemented, and you can see how I did it [for my bytecode manipulation library](https://github.com/jbosboom/bytecodelib/blob/master/src/edu/mit/streamjit/util/bytecode/ModuleClassLoader.java).  I agree it's not obvious at first, but it's simple.

Comment: Also note that having a ClassLoader instance associated with the class you're loading gives the JVM somewhere to look for any classes it references, which may solve your problem.  Unsafe.defineClass looks like it's trying the system class loader, which of course knows nothing about the classes you're generating.

Comment: @Jeffrey Bosboom: `Unsafe.defineClass` uses the `ClassLoader` that is passed as argument.

Comment: Yes, and in this case the stack trace suggests it's the system class loader, but the question code just says it's Enclosing.class's loader, and the code doesn't show how Enclosing was loaded (or if it's not dynamically generated).

Comment: @Jeffrey Bosboom: in the end, it doesn’t matter, what class loader the `CLASS_LOADER` argument represents. Whatever class loader it is, it will be used for resolving references, but can’t known the classes that have not been generated yet. Creating a custom loader which does know the (to be) generated classes, is unavoidable. But if you have a custom class loader, there is no need to use `Unsafe` anymore…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not specific to `Unsafe.defineClass`, but related to the program logic. Whenever you “*push*” multiple new classes, regardless of whether you use [`ClassLoader.defineClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass-java.lang.String-byte:A-int-int-) or [`Unsafe.defineClass`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/misc/Unsafe.java/#Unsafe.defineClass%28java.lang.String%2Cbyte%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.ClassLoader%2Cjava.security.ProtectionDomain%29), you have to avoid forward references, which precludes having loops in your class dependencies.

For the actual intended use cases of `Unsafe.defineClass`, e.g. reflective accessors, there is a clear dependency direction and hence, no problem, but for your use case, it’s not the right tool. You have to define a class loader which allows the JVM to “*pull*” the classes when needed, e.g.

```
void compileAndLoad(List<ICompilable> compilables) {
    Map<String,byte[]> compiled = new HashMap<>(compilables.size());
    for(ICompilable c: compilables)
        compiled.put(c.getFullName(), genBytecode(c));
    ClassLoader l = new ClassLoader(CLASS_LOADER) {
        @Override
        protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            byte[] code = compiled.get(name);
            if(code == null) throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
            return defineClass(name, code, 0, code.length);
        }
    };
    // the code below this line is questionable; it seems you are relying
    // on the side effects of a class initializer
    for(String name: compiled.keySet()) try {
        Class.forName(name, true, l);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) { throw new AssertionError(ex); }
}
```

Note that the code uses `Class.forName` rather than `loadClass` to enforce the initialization as your original code does. Normally, code should not rely on immediate initialization, but you’re not using the loaded classes for anything else, so it’s not clear, with what to substitute. The usual procedure would be to use `loadClass` for the class intended to be used subsequently and return it; the initialization (and loading and initialization of dependencies) would happen on its actual use.

Further note, that the entire code works without using `Unsafe`…